# ArcGIS REST API ElevationSync result is empty?

Tags: elevation, arcgis-rest-api

I would like to use the ArcGIS REST elevation service.

Providing a list of locations I would like to receive a list of elevations relative to these locations.

After some struggling with the syntax I was able to create a working (synchronous) request:

```
https://elevation.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/Tools/ElevationSync/GPServer/Profile/execute?InputLineFeatures={  
   "displayFieldName":"",
   "geometryType":"esriGeometryPolyline",
   "spatialReference":{  
      "wkid":4326
   },
   "fields":[  
      {  
         "name":"OID",
         "type":"esriFieldTypeOID",
         "alias":"OID"
      },
      {  
         "name":"Shape_Length",
         "type":"esriFieldTypeDouble",
         "alias":"Shape_Length"
      }
   ],
    "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPoint",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            52.50,
            13.30
          ],
          [
            52.60,
            13.40
          ],
          [
            52.70,
            13.50
          ],
          [
            52.80,
            13.60
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
   "exceededTransferLimit":false
}&ProfileIDField=&DEMResolution=&MaximumSampleDistance=&MaximumSampleDistanceUnits=&env:outSR=&env:processSR=&returnZ=true&returnM=true&f=json
```

But unfortunately the response result is empty

```
{  
   "results":[  
      {  
         "paramName":"OutputProfile",
         "dataType":"GPFeatureRecordSetLayer",
         "value":{  

         }
      }
   ],
   "messages":[  

   ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

> `http://elevation.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/Tools/ElevationSync/GPServer/Profile/execute?InputLineFeatures=%7B%22geometryType%22%3A%22esriGeometryPolyline%22%2C%22features%22%3A%5B%7B%22geometry%22%3A%7B%22paths%22%3A%5B%5B%5B52.50%2C13.30%5D%2C%5B52.60%2C13.40%5D%2C%5B52.70%2C13.50%5D%2C%5B52.80%2C13.60%5D%5D%5D%2C%22spatialReference%22%3A%7B%22wkid%22%3A4326%7D%7D%7D%5D%7D&ProfileIDField=OID&DEMResolution=FINEST&MaximumSampleDistance=50000&MaximumSampleDistanceUnits=&env%3AoutSR=4326&env%3AprocessSR=4326&returnZ=true&returnM=true&f=html`

Gives you a result of (HTML):

```
    {
 "results": [{
  "paramName": "OutputProfile",
  "dataType": "GPFeatureRecordSetLayer",
  "value": {
   "displayFieldName": "",
   "hasZ": true,
   "hasM": true,
   "geometryType": "esriGeometryPolyline",
   "spatialReference": {
    "wkid": 4326,
    "latestWkid": 4326
   },
   "fields": [
    {
     "name": "OBJECTID",
     "type": "esriFieldTypeOID",
     "alias": "OBJECTID"
    },
    {
     "name": "DEMResolution",
     "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
     "alias": "DEM Resolution",
     "length": 50
    },
    {
     "name": "ProductName",
     "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
     "alias": "Product Name",
     "length": 50
    },
    {
     "name": "Source",
     "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
     "alias": "Source",
     "length": 50
    },
    {
     "name": "Source_URL",
     "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
     "alias": "Source URL",
     "length": 84
    },
    {
     "name": "ProfileLength",
     "type": "esriFieldTypeDouble",
     "alias": "Length Meters"
    },
    {
     "name": "Shape_Length",
     "type": "esriFieldTypeDouble",
     "alias": "Shape_Length"
    }
   ],
   "features": [{
    "attributes": {
     "OBJECTID": 1,
     "DEMResolution": "1000m",
     "ProductName": "GEBCO_14",
     "Source": "BODC",
     "Source_URL": "https://www.bodc.ac.uk/data/online_delivery/gebco/",
     "ProfileLength": 46442.6656443336,
     "Shape_Length": 0.42426406878891676
    },
    "geometry": {
     "hasZ": true,
     "hasM": true,
     "paths": [[
      [
       52.500000000276486,
       13.300000000357443,
       -2205.644499999995,
       0
      ],
      [
       52.60000000029464,
       13.400000000375599,
       -2425.592399999994,
       15480.888500000001
      ],
      [
       52.7000000003128,
       13.500000000393754,
       -2572.166100000002,
       30961.777100000007
      ],
      [
       52.8000000003309,
       13.60000000041191,
       -2569.067200000005,
       46442.66560000001
      ]
     ]]
    }
   }],
   "exceededTransferLimit": false
  }
 }],
 "messages": []
}
```

This source was used and replaced with your coordinates
https://jsfiddle.net/6zc07mr9/9/